# Como multiplicar elementos dentro de uma array

Tags: javascript, array

Sou iniciante no JS e estou tentando entender como fazer para criar uma função que eu consiga triplicar qualquer valor dentro do Array. Esse tá sendo o meu código, mas não to conseguindo pensar muito bem em como resolver.

```
function tripleTheChances(chances){
    var chances = []
for(let index = 0; index <= chances.length; index++){
    chances[index] * 3
} 
    return chances[index] * 3
}
```

Comment: Vê se te ajuda: [array map javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: chances.map(x => x * 3) ?

Comment: Dentro do loop troque chances[index] * 3... por    chances[index] * =3;.... no  return apenas   chances.

Answer (score 0):

Basta usar o map

```
chances.map(x => x * 3)
```

ele percorrerá o array executando a função 'x * 3' por elemento

ou caso queira em uma função:

```
function tripleTheChances(chances){
   for(var index = 0; index < chances.length; index++){
      chances[index] *= 3;
   } 
   return chances;
}
```

usando um operador *= para fazer a operação com o valor que já está no index,assim atualizando ele